# How can I get full information from Console in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, logs, console

When I run Console, a lot of messages have the text `<private>` instead of details, even though my account is an Admin user account.  Here is an example for an application I'm writing and trying to debug:

```
default 17:12:50.191150 -0700   CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.ApplicationActivationObserver: handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application launched: <private>
default 17:12:50.311671 -0700   CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.ApplicationActivationObserver: handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application exited: <private>
```

How can I make this stop happening, and get full information about processes?

Comment: You may find my [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278685/168832) here helpful.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
```

[Show private messages in Console.app for Sierra](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/sierra-console-private/)

Comment: Is this working for you? I tried in macOS Sierra and some iOS 11 logs are still logged as `<private>`. I'm interested in seeing Apple's logs that do not come from my application but from Apple's frameworks such as `apsd`: `<private>: Received message for enabled topic '<private>' onInterface: NonCellular with payload '<private>' with priority 5 for device token: NO`

Comment: @Jan iOS 11 logs would be logged by your iOS device, not your Mac, so won't be affected by changing your Mac's private data setting.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to achieve this on iOS (by installing e.g. a new profile)?