# I was randomly logged out of my Mac on Sierra. Is there any way I can find the cause?

Tags: macos, login-screen

My retina MacBook Pro seems to like logging me out occasionally. Are there any logs which I can see that could explain why this happens?

Comment: This [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/278393/168832) may be of interest.