# How can I tell if someone logged in to my macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, console, hacking

It seems as though the activity in my Console has been deleted. Is this possible? There is no data before the login that led me here tonight.

Comment: Just checked my Mac and it also does not show any activity in the Console, which seems really weird.

Comment: Do you use any caches/logs cleaner apps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ever since macOS Sierra, it is possible that Console isn't displaying your past activity. You may want to refer to this question: [Sierra Console.app show earlier data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/278393/168832)

With regard to your question title, it's not clear exactly what details you're after, but one option open to you is using the `last` command in Terminal.

More specifically:

1. Launch Terminal (usually found in the Utilities folder)
2. Once the square cursor appears, type `last`
3. Press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key

This will produce a list of sessions in reverse time order.